# Using Entity Framework to Call Stored Procedure using context

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong I am new to this entity framework.  I am just trying to call this simple stored procedure which returns one or none persons.

This is the error I get:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'Model.Person'

**Stored Procedure:**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPersonByID] 
@personID int

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT        PersonID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Notes,  Reason, Diagnosis, DateEntered
    FROM            Person
    WHERE         PersonID = @personID
END
```

I updated my entity and see the stored procedure here. 
I also right clicked on my stored procedure and added a function import and tied it to the Person Entity.

**Code:**

```
private static Person GetPersonByID(int personID)
{
    try
    {
        ModelEntities context = new ModelEntities();

        return context.GetPersonByID(personID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `GetPersonByID` is returning an `ObjectResult` type, you need to convert it to your model. Something like this:

```
var persons = context.GetPersonByID(personID).Select(p => new Model.Person
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Age p.Age,
    ... etc ...
});

return persons.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it recognize that it is a person object through the Function Imports?  What happens if you have the same code but return a dataset of all the persons?  It seems like there is a more straight forward solution.

Comment: Think of the `ObjectResult` return type as a collection of your objects. Your code is trying to assign that collection to an individual `Model.Person`.

Comment: If the return type is actually `ObjectResult<Person>` then you may be able to simplify it to `return context.GetPersonByID(personID).SingleOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is mismatch between the SP result set and yours entity. Try to update entity same as result set or vice versa.

** It would be greatly helpful, if you can provide entity code as well. That way we can test within my test environment.

Comment: I wish I could upload not not sure how or what to do.  I updated my entity but I still have the same error.